# what is the recommended tool for platform independent application testing?

Tags: selenium, unit-testing, testing, appium

I am trying to find out a platform independent tool in which i can do the following .

1. Need to use it in macOS and windows
2. I have made my script which records the user actions using selenium IDE and exports a customised script which supports my application.
3. The same thing i want to do which will work on desktop application, web application and mobile application if possible as well.

Please suggest some tools which supports good customisation option and open source. I tried to use appium but i am not getting much help from it.
Thank you